# Do I need a Linux distro to learn the command line or would OS X be sufficient?

Tags: linux, command-line, osx

I am going to learn how to use the command line. Specifically, I will be using the book: ["The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction"](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php). Now, do I have to use a Linux distro to walk through the book, or would OS X be sufficient?

If I need a Linux distro, then would using it through a VM be sufficient or do I need to install it natively?

Comment: The only reason you would need to install an OS on physical hardware and not a VM would be for performance. If you're just trying to learn basic procedures than that's not going to be an issue. It's probably preferable to run something like Arch in a VM.

Comment: same discussion on http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208692/7057

Comment: Command-line is just a link between you and the system. Bash shell syntax may be the same, but when you need to deal with system specific parts, there's going to be differences. For instance, OS X doesnt have `/proc` filesystem, USB drives tend to appear in `/Volumes` not `/media/username` as on Ubuntu. CentOS has different `dhclient.conf` file . And so on and so on

Comment: @Serg Then, it seems like it would be better if I use the distro which the book uses.

Comment: Have you considered a book that isn't Linux specific? Or are you specifically trying to learn the Linux command line?

Comment: @br1ckb0t No actually I thought there are two variants: Linux and BSD. Hence, I thought I need to pick one. Are there any generic books on Unix?

Comment: @br1ckb0t By the way, _can_ there be a generic book on Unix? Because no matter which environment I pick, the kernel will be either Linux or BSD. Also, commands will be Linux or/and BSD. If that's right, can there be a generic book on Unix?

Comment: The proposed cross-site duplicate is **very clearly a different question**, about virtualisation performance on MacBooks. The question is not cross-posted.

Comment: @Utku I think what might help would be to separate a few concepts: using a command line, and the operating system you use it on. If you want to know your away a command line, OS X would work, as well as Linux, BSD, or even Windows with some effort. If you want to get to know UNIX or Linux, the command line is only a small part of that - it's only the interface through which you will interact with the OS. I think clarifying what you're going for will also make it easier to learn :)

Comment: @br1ckb0t I think I want to learn both the command line and Unix:)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would highly recommend running Linux in a VM. All the software is available freely to download and there is no practical difference between running in a VM and running natively for the purposes of learning the command line.

Furthermore, Linux command line mostly consists of *bash + GNU coreutils*, which is very different from BSD Unix (and OS X is a succedessor of BSD Unix). There is a very big difference of preferences in writing arguments in BSD Unix and GNU Linux. You can bite yourself even as non-newbie with different options to standard utilities like `ps` and `tar` if you work on both systems.

Using OS X when your book is Linux specific will regularly throw up inconsistencies and differences that will appear superficial when you're more experienced, but will simply be confusing when you're learning. Keep things easy for yourself.

This will also allow you to experiment without the worry of breaking your machine by deleting or changing any important files.

And last, though certainly not least, it will allow you to set up a SSH connection to your VM from your OS X Terminal, so you can get used to using SSH keys, and to the idea that it makes no difference whether your Linux server is a native machine, a local VM, or running out on AWS or Digital Ocean: it all works the same!

Comment: By the way, will I have the same directory structure in a VM vs. a native Linux as well?

Comment: Yes. For your purposes it's exactly the same as a native install.

Comment: This is the safest answer but depending on the book I would assume an introduction to the command line book would not show many (if any) of the differences.  After a glance at the manual the only thing that stuck out to me would be the explanation of the directory structure.

Comment: @Utku If /dev/sda or /dev/hda is mentioned in the book and you can't find it in your install, try looking for /dev/vda. This is the only possible difference I can think of, that would matter to you.

Comment: You don't even have to use a VM, using a [live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) is also possible if you don't want to take up a bunch of space on your HD. It can also be booted from a flash drive, and creating a CD/bootable flash drive takes very little time.

Answer (score 18):

OS X is sufficient to learn the command line as it is a certified UNIX and conforms to POSIX.  If you are looking at Linux specific command line book you have to keep in mind that the userland tools in OS X are derived from BSD while the tools on Linux are GNU and there are some subtle (and not so subtle) differences between them.

If you want to learn with GNU tools you can install a GNU userland through macports or homebrew, or can do a full Linux install in a VM.

Comment: So, I guess that there is no "generic" book on command line? A book will either use GNU or BSD tools. Is that right?

Comment: If you have a book on a shell (e.g. `bash`), it'll suit just about any system that runs it. It varies when you start using operating system features or specific tools outside the shell.

Comment: @teppic But how useful is a shell just by _itself_? AFAIK, a shell by itself is useless since it doesn't have any command to execute. Even the most basic commands like `ls` must be either from GNU or BSD (please correct if I am wrong). So, I think this means that I need to pick one toolchain (or environment) and start learning the command line there. Is that right?

Comment: @Utku the commands are the same (for the most part) but options and output may differ (often because GNU implements many extensions).  It easy to go back and forth between BSD and GNU tools.

Comment: @casey So I might just start with the book on OS X. Then if I encounter with behavior not described as in the book, I might try it on Linux or just look at the BSD variant of the same command?

Comment: @Utku the shell's a complete (if simple) programming language, with things like job control, input/output redirection, and so on, so there's a lot to learning them fully. The basic OS commands are mostly the same - the GNU tools were developed to be as compatible as possible with the original Unix tools.

Comment: @teppic I see. But still I must use a toolchain to interact with the shell and to learn it. But since GNU and BSD commands are similar, does it makes sense to start at OS X, then if I encounter with a behavior not described in the book, try the same command in Linux or check its BSD variant?

Comment: @Utku just use it, it'll be fine.  If something doesn't match the book, google it.  Both BSD and GNU tools are well documented.  Your book should also teach you the `man` command, which also exists on OS X, which documents the tools on your system.  So if something doesn't match the book, `df` for example, which will report in 512b vs 1k blocks on GNU, you can `man df` to read about the command.

Comment: @Utku Books on OS X tend to focus on the GUI and Apple's own stuff rather than its BSD derived parts. Most good books on command line, shells, etc. tend to be quite general, since Unix systems have always had differences in command options and so on.

Comment: @casey Thanks. One last thing: If I ever need to run a command on Linux, would running it on a Linux in VM or on a natively installed Linux make any difference?

Comment: @Utku Well, that depends on the command. For exampe `lspci` in a VM won't tell you much about your real PCI devices. But in general they should work the same.

Comment: If you are on a tight budget, there are some excellent older Unix books that can be found very cheap used and that are not flavor-specific, in that they do a good job of covering both BSD and SystemV variants: I particularly like [Unix for the Impatient](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0201823764).

Answer (score 10):

Some good answers so far, but one more reason to stay away from the default OS X command line tools is they are very old versions. For example, OS X's `grep` is from 2004, and `bash` is from 2007! The [reason](http://robservatory.com/behind-os-xs-modern-face-lies-an-aging-collection-of-unix-tools/) is that Apple refuses to ship tools licenced under the GPL3.

If you didn't want to install Linux proper, you could manually install the latest versions (perhaps via some port system like MacPorts, Fink or Homebrew).

Answer (score 3):

First difference:

```
ls * -lah
```

Works on linux, fails on mac (parameters must come first). Use a VM or get a book for mac os. You should learn the one you will use more later and then the differences.

Comment: You should say `ls * -lah` works on Linux the way it works on Linux, and it works on OS X the way it works on OS X.  The way it works on OS X is *correct* [according to POSIX (12. Utility Conventions / 12.2 Utility Syntax Guidelines / Guideline 9)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html): “All options should precede operands on the command line.”  As described in [getopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html): “If … the environment variable **POSIXLY_CORRECT** is set, then option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered.”

Answer (score 3):

The best way to learn unix is to have real work to do with it.  I'd say it's worth encountering the differences between the Linux-specific examples in your book and the Mac versions of the standard tools, just to be able to work with your own files and data in your normal working environment (OS X).

Encountering the differences will also be a valuable learning experience, even if it's frustrating at times.

Having a Linux VM as well to practice with (esp. for potentially dangerous commands) is also useful but nothing beats real-world usage for learning.